# Server 2012 Backup uses 4x its size on disk

Tags: backup, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-backup

i am having a problem with one of my server backups. More specifically the disk space it seems to use but shouldnt.

The `WindowsImageBackup` folder for the Server in question is about 600gb which would be totally ok. Sadly though the properties of the backup drive show that the space used is 2,4TB. Besides the backup there is nothing on there. File History is also disabled.

Does someone have an idea why this occurs and what i can do to decrease the used space for the backup?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be due to shadow copies of your backups. Run this command in elevated `cmd` to view reserved storage for shadow copies (replace `X` with your drive letter):

```
vssadmin List ShadowStorage /On=X:
```

To lists all existing shadow copies of a specified volume use:

```
vssadmin List Shadows /For=X:
```

You can delete shadow copies. If `/Oldest` argument is given, the oldest shadow copy on the volume is deleted. If `/All` argument is given, then all shadow copies on all volumes that can be deleted will be deleted.  If `/Shadow=ShadowId` argument is given, the shadow copy with that Shadow Copy ID will be deleted.

```
vssadmin Delete Shadows /For=X: /Oldest
```

Shadow storage also can be resized (resizing may cause shadow copies to disappear):

```
vssadmin Resize ShadowStorage /on=X: /For=X: /MaxSize=10GB
```

More information:

- [Backup Version and Space Management in Windows Server Backup](http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2009/06/22/backup-version-and-space-management-in-windows-server-backup.aspx)
- [Identifying how much disk space is used for restore points in Windows Vista](http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2006/11/16/identifying-how-much-disk-space-is-used-for-restore-points-in-windows-vista.aspx)
- [DiskShadow (DiskShadow.exe replaces vshadow in Windows Server 2008 onwards)](http://ss64.com/nt/diskshadow.html)

Comment: actually shadow copies was the first thing i looked at, strangely the GUI showed that they were disabled but vssadmin reports 1,8TB which perfectly aligns with the missing space. thank you